# Gnuplot: undefined value during function evaluation

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to fit the function f(x)=exp(a*x) on Gnuplot. It keeps giving me the error 'undefined value during function evaluation'. I use the following code:

```
y(x)=exp(a*x)
a = 60

fit y(x) 'data.txt' using 1:2 via a
plot y(x), 'data.txt' using 1:2 notitle
```

The error is coming from the fourth line in the above bit of code. I have set the directory properly but did not it include in the piece of code above.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show the data you want to fit or at least an excerpt of it.

Comment: Ah sorry you can see an excerpt from my data below. ` 8,701 1032,000 1025,000
9,701 974,000 963,000
10,701 941,000 931,000
11,701 911,000 901,000
12,701 883,000 873,000
13,701 857,000 847,000
14,701 832,000 823,000
15,701 808,000 800,000
16,701 785,000 777,000
17,701 764,000 756,000
18,701 743,000 735,000
19,701 724,000 716,000
20,701 706,000 699,000
21,701 689,000 681,000
22,701 671,000 664,000
23,701 655,000 648,000
24,701 639,000 633,000
25,701 624,000 618,000
26,701 609,000 603,000` The first two columns were used for the fit.

Comment: The formatting of the data is lost in the comment. Please edit the question and add the data there. There should be an "Edit" button/link just below the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
8,701 1032,000 1025,000 
9,701 974,000 963,000
...
26,701 609,000 603,000
```

First, by default gnuplot expects decimal numbers to be written with '.' as decimal sign. To change this, use:

```
set decimalsign ','
```

Second, and more important to your question, gnuplot internally uses [double precision numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). They go up to about `1e308`.  In the first iteration of the fit there are calculations like `exp(a*x)` with `a=60` and `x=26`, which results in `exp(1560) = 3e677` - way too large, hence the error message.

Third, an exponential function `f(x) = exp(a*x)` starts with `f(0) = 1` and is increasing for positive `a`, your data starts at `f(0) > 1000` and is decreasing. Therefore I would try a setup like this:

```
set decimalsign ','

y(x)=b*exp(-a*x)
a = 0.1
b = 1000

fit y(x) 'data.txt' using 1:2 via a,b
plot y(x), 'data.txt' using 1:2 notitle
```

Result:

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = 0.0286709        +/- 0.0005953    (2.076%)
b               = 1256.51          +/- 12.12        (0.9647%)
```

It's up to you to decide if the function really represents the underlying data.

[image: fit]

Comment: I thought this did not gave the expected result for a but turned out to be spot on. Thanks for the help!